# Creating conditions inside a Runnable in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created a code that reads data thrown to my android device from an Arduino. It goes like this:

```
 public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        final StringBuilder readMessage = new StringBuilder();
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                final String string_now = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                readMessage.append(string_now);
                // final int finalBytes = bytes;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvBPM.setText(string_now);
                        readMessage.setLength(0);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Lost!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is located inside my 'private class ThreadConnected extends Thread'

Now the values held by string_now are numbers. I want to tell the user if the value stored there is greater than 150 or less than 50. Here's a code I've tried but I doesn't fully work.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   final int getValue = Integer.getValue(Integer.parseInt(string_now));
                   if (getValue > 150 || getValue < 50) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Unstable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                   else {
                    tvBPM.setText(string_now);
                    readMessage.setLength(0); }
                }
            });
```

Any tips on how I can make this work? Thank you.

Comment: "Doesn't fully work" is not really useful information. Can you provide more information on what you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: The code displays the heart rate values on the tvBPM from a prototype that I have created. Now I want the values shown in tvBPM be checked if it meets the conditions (i.e. the if else statement). Currently, the app just closes after I've pressed the Start button which in turn directs it the thread containing the runOnUiThread() code. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
final String string_now = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

This code will run forever even after the peer closes the connection, when it will start showing rubbish, giving `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, or whatever. You are missing the following between those two lines:

```
if (bytes == -1)
{
    break;
}
```

and the following after the `catch` block:

```
finally
{
    try
    {
        connectedInputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        // whatever ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. But I removed those two codes above because it's supposed to catch all values from the arduino while it is switched to on. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: It can't catch anything after the Arduino has disconnected. There are no further values to 'catch'. You would have to reconnect, or wait until the peer reconnected.